# Moving a 3d object back and forth between points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics

I tried to make a script that moves an object back and forth between two points. But it just flies in the ifinity. I tried to find the problem whole evening but idk.
here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementBetweenPoints : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] keyPoints;
    public float speed;
    private int currentKeyPoint;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        transform.position = keyPoints[0].position;
        currentKeyPoint = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

        if (transform.position == keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position)
        {
            currentKeyPoint++;
        }

        if (currentKeyPoint >= keyPoints.Length)
        {
            currentKeyPoint = 0;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `Debug.Log` to see if it ever makes it to one of your `keyPoints`. Does the `currentKeyPoint` value ever change?

Comment: it works on my unity, i just plugged it in, make sure you have your transforms and speed set in the inspector

Comment: Don't compare float using equal operator. Use ranges or some eplison value because depending on the frame rate, speed etc transform.position could never been equal to current keypoint .

Comment: @Heisenbug that's not quite true, `Vector3.MoveTowards` will account for that. According to the docs, `If the target is closer than maxDistanceDelta/ then the returned value will be equal to target` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Comment: But yes, typically I would agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Your script works fine as it is. you need to make sure that speed is set to a value greater than 0 in the inspector, and that the keypoints array contains some gameobjects in the inspector too, and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the problem comes with this part of the code where you check if the position of the object is equal at some waypoint. Instead of:

```
if (transform.position == keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position)
{
     currentKeyPoint++;
}
```

try to do something less agressive, and give a bit of margin like:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position - keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position) <= min_Distance)
{
     currentKeyPoint++;
}
```

because it's almost impossible that two objects with different speeds match at the same point. Instead of this, you'll use min_Distance to check it.